# scala returning tuples from functions

Tags: scala, scala-2.8

Lets say I have something like this:

```
def f () = {

   var v = someLookupToV()

   match v {
       case Some(v) => (v.id, someOtherLookup(v.id))
       case None => None // <<-- doesn't work, but I'm not sure what to put there!
   }
```

}

Sort of assuming that someLookupToV returns some object, that has a field id, and then I have some other lookup based on v.id. I want to return both values as a tuple. But what do I do if Some(v) doesn't match anything? What do I return? None and (None,None) didnt' work. Scala accepted (null,null) but I've got no clue if that's the right thing to do...

Comment: `null` exists in Scala mainly for interoperability with Java. It's better to avoid it as much as possible and use `Option`, `Some` and `None` when you have values that might be empty.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would not have the function return `(Int, Option[Int])`, but instead `Option[(Int, Option[Int])]`:

```
def f = someLookupToV match {
  case Some(v) => Some(v.id, someOtherLookup(v.id))
  case None => None
}
```

or, somewhat shorter:

```
def f = someLookupToV.map(v => (v.id, someOtherLookup(v.id)))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return (None, None), your "case Some" line needs to return a tuple of (Option, Option).

As written in your example, your `case Some` is returning (Int, Option). That's assuming your `v.id` is an Int and someOtherLookup returns an Option.